# Creating a subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, paraview

I am trying to use th `subprocess` module along with the `Popen` class to create and run a process. Up until now, I always succeeded calling any program I wanted.

Now I am trying to call `paraview` (version 3.8.1) with a python script attached to it as a parameter like so:

```
paraview --script=script.py
```

If I run this command from console it works just fine. If I try to run it with my `Popen` class it fails with the error message:

```
/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site.py:157: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/linecache.py:127: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site.py:157: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
ERROR: In /home/kitware/Kitware/ParaView-3.8.1/source/Utilities/VTKPythonWrapping/Executable/vtkPVPythonInteractiveInterpretor.cxx, line 75
vtkPVPythonInteractiveInterpretor (0x124e9d0): Failed to locate the InteractiveConsole object.
```

Paraview itself is starting up. But is the error message due to the fact, that paraview itself has a python interpreter which it is using? Or can I tweak my `Popen` calling routine which looks like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("paraview --script=script.py", bufsize = -1, shell = True)
```

How can it be, that a process can be created from console but not with the `Popen`-call from above?

#### Edit

I downloaded and installed a paraview version where python 2.7 is running inside (and not python 2.5 of the version I used above) and the call of `Popen` works. So this must have something to do with the python version of paraview. The only question remaining is: Why does it even matter when I start a process with `Popen`?

Comment: I think `Popen` doesn't have any problem to execute a command in a different process. It's the `python2.5` process that automatically imports a wrong `site.py`. I think that if you look at the rules used to locate `site.py` [here](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) you'll find out what's the problem in your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things which are strage:

1. Normally, this call shouldn't work at all. As you have `shell=False`, you would need to use a sequence as 1st parameter:

   ```
   p = subprocess.Popen(("paraview", "--script=script.py"), bufsize=-1)
   ```

   (`shell=False` is the default.)
2. You seem to mix several Python versions:

   ```
   /home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site.py:157: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
   ```

The said `site.py` uses the `with` keyword. That's ok, because it is intended for Python 2.7. The python version you are running seems to come from Python 2.5. There was no `with` back in 2.4, and in 2.6 it was already present.

Comment: Regarding #1: I am really sorry for the `shell = False`. I only used it for debugging issues and I posted it by mistake. #2 You are right, paraview uses python 2.5. But why is this an issue if I only create a process with python 2.7?

Comment: The fact that `paraview` uses python 2.5 and you're using python 2.7 shouldn't be a problem for `subprocess`. Anyway, have you checked that `paraview` is really using python 2.5? I mean, that python 2.5 isn't being shadowed by python 2.7 as the default python version?

Comment: @jcollado Doing `sys.version` gives `2.5.4 (r254:67916, Sep  9 2010, 17:20:10)`. If this doesn't reveal the shadow, please tell me how to check for the version correctly.

Comment: I don't know how python is launched in paraview, but probably it's the first python binary found in your PATH so you should just need to check the output of `which python`.

Comment: Anyway, for what is worth, I've installed paraview in using the packaging system in my distribution and haven't found any problem (python 2.5 isn't really required). If you're having trouble with a local python installation, maybe you should just try the packaging system (or ask your sysadmin if you don't have installation rights).

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting doesn't seem to be related to `subprocess.Popen`. I'd say that what you need is either `shell=True`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("paraview --script=script.py", shell = True)
```

or separate `args` in a sequence:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['paraview', '--script=script.py'])
```

I've never used `bufsize`, but I don't think it makes any difference here.

Comment: I get the same error message if I do `subprocess.Popen(["paraview --script=script.py"], shell = True)`...

Comment: It should be ``["paraview", "--script=script.py"]``